# R - scraping nodes from website pages - how to insert individual pages link in the final data frame

Tags: r, web-scraping, hyperlink

Dear Stackoverflow users,
I am trying to scrape two nodes in different pages from a website (Psychology today, and the pages refer to mental health professionals, MHPs).

First, I create a scraping function and then I create a loop that includes this function.
Eventually, I am able to create a data frame. However, I would like to include--as a third variable--the full link to individual pages I have scraped.
How can I include this information in the data frame?

This is the loop:

```
j <- 1 #set the running variable = to 1 (the MHP id will increase by one)
MHP_codes <-  c(150130:150170) #therapist identifier range
df_list <- vector(mode = "list", length(MHP_codes)) #set up the vector 
                                                    #that collects individual
                                                    #MHP information
for(code1 in MHP_codes) {
  delayedAssign("do.next", {next})
  URL <- paste0('https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/illinois/', code1)
  #Reading the HTML code from the website
  URL <-  tryCatch(read_html(URL), 
           error = function(e) force(do.next)) 
                #tryCatch catches also those with missing URL
                #however, if an error occur in those pages
                #the loop stops; this is why we need delayedAssign
                #and force(do.next) in tryCatch
  df_list[[j]] <- getProfile(URL) #the function puts the scraped data
                                  #into a row  
  na.omit(df_list) #this function eliminates rows with only NAs, which happens if the URL does not exist
  j <- j + 1
}
final_df <- rbind.fill(df_list) #gather the vectors into one unique data set
```

Should I modify the scraping function? that is getProfile() or can I create the new variable within the loop, but outside of the scraping function? and how do I do that? Have been thinking about it for days, and now, with the complete data set, I am still dragging this issue.

This post is related to other two, with additional information on the scraping function as well [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58054707/web-scraping-and-looping-through-pages-with-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58126097/trycatch-function-works-on-most-non-existent-urls-but-it-does-not-work-in-at-l/58138181#58138181).

Comment: Either option has it pros and cons.  If you are sure there is a one to one relationship between the URL and the number of lines in the data frame (i.e. no missing data) you could just `cbind` the vector of URL to final_df: `cbind(final_df, paste0('https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/illinois/', MHP_codes)`

Comment: very interesting. I think that it should work even if the URL did not exist. In fact, I should be more precise: all of the URL exists, but many of them do not have anything to scrape (i.e. "code1" was not associated to any MHP; as in this case: https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/illinois/150152)

Comment: @DaveT If I intervene within the loop, should I write below na.omit() something like: cbind(df_list, paste0('https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/therapists/illinois/', code1). If I insert it before na.omit(), rows that would have been completely filled with NAs will have now variable with a non-NA value and thus this useless observation won't be dropped.

Comment: Yes, if some URL don't return any data, then my previous comment won't work.  If you intervene within the loop then something like: `df_list[[j]]<-cbind(df_list[[j]], URL)` should work.